# Is Dependency Injection with AngularJS and Webpack superfluous?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, dependency-injection, webpack-2

I'm working on an AngularJS application and trying to convert it from a Gulp bundling system over to Webpack. I've been searching for some time now for arguments for/against utilizing the AngularJS dependency injection in tandem with `require()` statements for Webpack dependency graphs. Why might someone continue to inject dependencies with AngularJS, or will that just add bloat and repeat functionality that Webpack gives us out of the box?

Is there any reason we might maintain both the `require()` statements AND dependency injection??

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002804/angularjs-use-es6-imports-instead-of-angular-di-system